# Non-persistent jms message get lost for non durable subscriber

Tags: activemq-classic, persistent

I have started with ActiveMQ just one day ago, so my knowledge on it is limited. 
My target is to check the ActiveMQ stability and throughput in different scenario for JMS message. 
So, following is one scenario. 
1. I am publishing 1 mil non-persistent synchronous messages to topic and subscribing it synchronously non durable manner. One publisher and one subscriber. 
2. The broker, publisher and subscriber is up during the test.

Unfortunately nearly most of the times(only one time I got all messages out of 14 try),  I am not getting all the messages(1 mil) in subscriber end. nearly 5500 messages are lost.

I did the same test for tibco ems and ibm mq and did not get this issue.

So, for ActiveMQ, if I need all messages to be received, is it necessary to use persistent message and durable subscriber always?

Don't think form the angle of guaranteed messaging or fail-over scenario.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks, 
Smith

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your exact scenario. But ActiveMQ will limit the memory used for buffering messages when the producer is faster than the consumer by dropping old messages above a certain limit.

This is [configurable](http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html).

Comment: correct one. I have managed the loss using `constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy = -1`.